# Blur input field on submit on Modal not working React Native

Tags: react-native, blur, textinput, react-native-textinput, react-native-modal

I have an input field on a modal, but it cant blur on button click so it takes 2x tap to press the button.

I tried `Keyboard.dismiss` and `useRef` both are not working.
I also tried `onSubmitEditing` prop is not working either

My modal component looks like this.

```
        <Overlay 
            isVisible={isModalOpen}
            fullScreen={false}
            animationType="slide"
            overlayStyle={{width:widthModal}}
        >
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
                
                <View>
                    <Text>{dataModal.name}</Text>
                    <Input
                        ref={inputRef}
                        value={dataModal.input}
                        onChangeText={(value) => onTempDataChange(value)}
                        onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
                        onEndEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
                        autoFocus
                        blurOnSubmit
                    />
                </View>
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Button                       
                            title="Save"
                            onPress={() => {
                                inputRef.current.blur();
                                Keyboard.dismiss
                                onSubmit()
                            }}
 
                        />
                    </View>
                    
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </Overlay>
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the code in snack for checking?